# Hazelcast: Load on Startup

Tags: onload, hazelcast

Newbie to Hazelcast...

Interested to find out how do I get Hazelcast cluster to populate a map on startup. Read up and implemented com.hazelcast.core.MapLoader, then in my Spring config I have the following:

```
           <hz:map name="products">
                <hz:map-store write-delay-seconds="0" class-name="my.company.ProductMapLoader"
                              enabled="true" initial-mode="EAGER" />
                <hz:indexes>
                    <hz:index attribute="clientId" ordered="true"/>
                </hz:indexes>
            </hz:map>
```

I even set the **initial-mode="EAGER"** to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Are you able to do this ? If yes could you please comment how?

Answer (score 4):

This is just the config part. You need to define a bean for the map that uses this config (outside of the `hz:instance` tag)

Here is a sample;

`<hz:map id="products" instance-ref="instance" name="products" />`

Above, `id` is your handle to that bean (regular spring bean id), `name` is the reference to your map config.